# Sequential SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

A newby to SQL question so please forgive me

Any clues of a simple SQL query? I am trying to sort a series a results where there is a break in a range of numbers.

eg R00000D to R99999D.

However some of the number have been allocated in a none sequential order example R00000D to R12549D then the next sequence is R200001D to R50000D.

So I would like to group these in blocks

i.e

```
R00000D to R12549D
R20000D to R50000D
R69154D to R99999D
```

The only way that I have been able to do is to export to excel and a long winded way and counting the columns.

My start query is a simple

```
Select *
FROM SystemNote
WHERE Note LIKE 'R%'
```

Comment: Hi there I'm using SQL server

Answer (score 1):

I would make a table with your ordering requirements and join to it -- this allows you to modify the table if your requirements change.  Here I do it as an inline table but you could have an actual table or CTE.

This code should work on most platforms with slight modifications.  I know it will work on DB2 and I believe Oracle.  Not sure if the values statement works in SQL Server.  You might need to change to SELECT / UNION ALLs.

```
SELECT *
FROM SystemNote
LEFT JOIN (
  VALUES
    ('R00000D','R12549D',1),
    ('R20000D','R50000D',2),
    ('R69154D','R99999D',3)
) AS ORD(S,E,ORD) ON Note BETWEEN ORD.S AND ORD.E
WHERE Note LIKE 'R%'
ORDER BY COALESCE(ORD.ORD,4) ASC, Note
```

> Note, this puts any item not in your defined ranges at the end.  This may (or may not) be what you want.  You didn't define it.

Comment: The OP gave an example, not an hard-coded boundaries.

Comment: I've no idea what you mean @DuduMarkovitz -- I believe we read the same question.  If he wants a group by he can use ORD.ORD in the group by statement.  This join will be much faster than using the substr function

Answer (score 1):

For use with databases that support the windows functions.
Might require small changes for different providers.

**Demo**

```
create table SystemNote (Note char(7));

insert into SystemNote values 
 ('R00000D'),('R00001D'),('R00002D'),('R00003D'),('R00004D')
,('R00012D'),('R00013D')
,('R00015D'),('R00016D'),('R00017D'),('R00018D')
,('R00021D')
,('R00025D'),('R00026D'),('R00027D')
```

---

```
select      min (Note)  as from_Note
           ,max (Note)  as to_Note
           ,count (*)   as Notes

from       (select      Note
                       ,row_number () over (order by Note)  as rn

            from        SystemNote

            where       Note like 'R%'
            ) sn

group by    cast (substr(Note,2,5) as int) - rn

order by    from_Note
```

---

```
+-----------+---------+-------+
| from_note | to_note | notes |
+-----------+---------+-------+
| R00000D   | R00004D | 5     |
+-----------+---------+-------+
| R00012D   | R00013D | 2     |
+-----------+---------+-------+
| R00015D   | R00018D | 4     |
+-----------+---------+-------+
| R00021D   | R00021D | 1     |
+-----------+---------+-------+
| R00025D   | R00027D | 3     |
+-----------+---------+-------+
```

---

```
select  dense_rank () over (order by cast (substr(Note,2,5) as int)-rn) as group_id
       ,row_number () over (partition by cast (substr(Note,2,5) as int)-rn order by note) as seq
       ,min (Note) over (partition by cast (substr(Note,2,5) as int)-rn) as from_Note
       ,max (Note) over (partition by cast (substr(Note,2,5) as int)-rn) as to_Note
           ,Note

from       (select      Note
                       ,row_number () over (order by Note)  as rn

            from        SystemNote

            where       Note like 'R%'
            ) sn

order by    Note
```

---

```
+----------+-----+-----------+---------+---------+
| group_id | seq | from_note | to_note | note    |
+----------+-----+-----------+---------+---------+
| 1        | 1   | R00000D   | R00004D | R00000D |
+----------+-----+-----------+---------+---------+
| 1        | 2   | R00000D   | R00004D | R00001D |
+----------+-----+-----------+---------+---------+
| 1        | 3   | R00000D   | R00004D | R00002D |
+----------+-----+-----------+---------+---------+
| 1        | 4   | R00000D   | R00004D | R00003D |
+----------+-----+-----------+---------+---------+
| 1        | 5   | R00000D   | R00004D | R00004D |
+----------+-----+-----------+---------+---------+
| 2        | 1   | R00012D   | R00013D | R00012D |
+----------+-----+-----------+---------+---------+
| 2        | 2   | R00012D   | R00013D | R00013D |
+----------+-----+-----------+---------+---------+
| 3        | 1   | R00015D   | R00018D | R00015D |
+----------+-----+-----------+---------+---------+
| 3        | 2   | R00015D   | R00018D | R00016D |
+----------+-----+-----------+---------+---------+
| 3        | 3   | R00015D   | R00018D | R00017D |
+----------+-----+-----------+---------+---------+
| 3        | 4   | R00015D   | R00018D | R00018D |
+----------+-----+-----------+---------+---------+
| 4        | 1   | R00021D   | R00021D | R00021D |
+----------+-----+-----------+---------+---------+
| 5        | 1   | R00025D   | R00027D | R00025D |
+----------+-----+-----------+---------+---------+
| 5        | 2   | R00025D   | R00027D | R00026D |
+----------+-----+-----------+---------+---------+
| 5        | 3   | R00025D   | R00027D | R00027D |
+----------+-----+-----------+---------+---------+
```